# Table view controller w/search bar and creating a database

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard

Lets say I have a basic table view controller w/search display controller that has prototype cells. I want to be able to create a database separate from the storyboard such that the view controller can receive data via the search bar (Like a dictionary except with math eq.). In other words I want to know how to create this database and link it to the table view controller via search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ios` 7 and lower, you can use [this](http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/) tutorial. It's very easy to follow and very straightforward.

But if you need it for `ios` 8, due to the fact that a lot of things got deprecated, you can use [this](https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/Sample-UISearchController) class from github.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Glad I was able to help!! Don't forget to accept the answer. (it's the check mark under the up/down votes)